# What is the "pdm" stat in the "rms" R package?

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit, ordered-logit, rms

I am building an ordinal logistic regression model (ORM). In order to fit my ORM model, I am using the 'orm' function of 'rms' package from R (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf).

Now I am trying to assess the goodness of fit of my model. By reading the R documentation, I can see the following statement in the 'stat' property of the 'orm' object (p. 98):

> (...) Nagelkerke $R^2$ index, the $g$-index, $gr$ (the $g$-index on the odds
>   ratio scale), and **pdm (the mean absolute difference between 0.5 and
>   the predicted probability that $Y\geq q$  the marginal median)** (...).

I don't have enough background to understand the short description of the pdm measure. But when I try to do more research on this measure, I am not able to find related material (e.g. I've been finding "prescription drug misuse"). In summary, my question is:

Would you know if the 'pdm' measure has some synonym which is more widely used? Or can you provide some references where I can study the pdm metric?

Comment: I've tried to look it up possibly it is related to D. R. Cox "Two further applications of a model for binary regression" Biometrika , Dec., 1958, Vol. 45, No. 3/4 (Dec., 1958), pp. 562-565 but I could not make it work.

Comment: @FrankHarrell you wrote that package not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know yet about the background of the statistic but below is an illustration how it is computed.

$$pdm = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left| \hat{P}(Y \geq median|X_k) - 0.5 \right| $$

It is an indication of how much the conditional predicted probability varies around the point of the marginal median.

```
library(rms)

###
###  generate some data according to a logit model
###
set.seed(1)
n = 10^2
k = 5
x = runif(n,-2,2)  # predictor
noise = rnorm(n,0,1)   # noise
y = x + noise        # latent variable
bounds = seq(-2,2,1) # values to be predicted
z = as.numeric(sapply(y, FUN = function(yi) sum(bounds<yi)))  # ordinal variable

### compute ordinal regression
mod = orm(z ~ x, family =probit)


### marginal median of the data
median = mod$stats[3]
### predictions hat p(y>=median | x) for all x in the data
pr = coef(mod)[median] + coef(mod)[k+1]*x
prs = pnorm(pr)
### mean absolute deviation  ... 0.3308655
mean(abs(prs-0.5))
### value from the function  ... 0.3308655
mod$stats[14]
```

Comment: That's it.  The idea behind this probability is that if the model has not discrimination ability ($R^{2} = D_{xy} = \rho = 0$), it will estimate the same probability of $Y\geq y$ for every observation.  And depending on how one handles ties the probability of exceeding the sample median will be 0.5 for all $X$.  How far from 0.5 it actually predicts across $X$ is a measure of discrimination ability.  As an aside, I'm adding some new pseudo $R^2$ measures to the `rms` package as described [here](https://hbiostat.org/bib/r2.html).

Answer (score 0):

This link: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/5.1-0/topics/validate.lrm
describes pdm as a "new" metric, which would imply that is has not been used before.

Comment: If this is new why would a question about it have come up in 2014?

Comment: I meant new in the sense of not previously reported in the literature, or used outside of the rms package. I myself am not sure, I am just going on based on what they are saying in the package it sounds like this is a new metric they came up with, as opposed to a standard metric that they gave a different name to.